# Google Sheets/Excel: IMAGE() formula into plain URL

Tags: google-sheets

I am converting a Google Sheets file into a CSV format.

Some cells have an image inserted into them via `=IMAGE("https://placekitten.com/200/300")`

I need to be able to extract in plain text `https://placekitten.com/200/300`

Is this possible? I've tried `SUBSTITUTE` but of course that doesn't work.

Thanks to whoever can solve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(A2); """(.*)""")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I didn't know about FORMULATEXT :)

Answer (score 1):

I thought that explaining @player0’s answer would be nice, especially for future people.

His answer can be split in 2 parts:

- Using `FORMULATEXT` to get the formula
- Using a regular expression to extract the URL from it

The first part is `FORMULATEXT`. It is pretty self explanatory: it takes a cell and returns the formula as string.

The second part is using a regular expression ([see wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and [documentation on the exact syntax used by Google](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)) to extract the URL. In this case @player0 relies on the fact that the URL is the only quoted text of that formula. So using the regex `"(.+)"` will match the quoted part inside the quotes of the formula, and thus only the URL. When using literal strings in a formula, you need to surround them with quotes (eg `hello` as `"hello"`). Double quotes need to be doubled (eg `aaa"aaa` is written as `"aaa""aaa"`). So `"(.+)"` becomes `"""(.+)"""`.

### References

- [FORMULATEXT (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)
- [REGEXEXTRACT (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)
- [Regular expression (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)
- [RE2 syntax (Google’s RE2 repository on GitHub)](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)