# Formula Parse Error with double quotes in Regex expression

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to add a Regex expression to `REGEXMATCH`, but every time I try Google sheets adds a closing parenthesis and breaks the formula giving me a parse error. I'v tried to escape the single quote, double quote and parenthesis, but with no luck any tips? also tried to add the regex to a cell and reference that, but didn't behave as expected

this is the regex I'm trying to add `['"(]`

Comment: Can you show your full formula?

Comment: =REGEXMATCH(C2,"['"(]")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to double them like:

```
['""(]
```

example: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/66028064/5632629**

Comment: Thanks  to all. you are right I had to do a double quote. in this case its fine, but its funny way of doing it. in some scenarios that wouldn't be good if I want to check for a single double quote then what should I do?

Comment: @Osh you can still use CHAR(34)